# Transparent canvas in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to create an app, that works as a framework for using e.g. the ipad. 
That means, that you will start the app and **continue working normally** with it, while suddenly e.g. animals cross the screen.

Hence the app should create a transparent canvas on top of the ipad user interface where all animations can be played.

Do packages for that exist?

Comment: Are you trying to do this within your own app, or draw over whatever application the user happens to be running? It's not clear from the question, and the latter is impossible on iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're asking for isn't currently supported in flutter. The closest you can get is notifications at the moment using a package [like this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

I'm assuming you want to make something along the lines of this [goose desktop application for windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=EQx6fyrZDWM&feature=emb_logo). Your best bet in this situation is to go native and maybe even make your own dart package.

Comment: Do you know, if it is possible with Swift?

Comment: I'm not for certain since my specality isn't swift. The first thing that comes to mind is taking something like the facebook chat bubble, or youtubes video preview and seeing you can extend that to fit your needs. Here's a tutorial I saw a while ago that may help to get you started on your research

https://medium.com/@dimabauer/creating-a-chat-bubble-which-looks-like-a-chat-bubble-in-imessage-the-advanced-way-2d7497d600ba